# video output to stream in mp4 format fail

Tags: c#, .net, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm trying to output mp4 file from the input stream

```
ffmpeg -f mp4 -i pipe:0 -an -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -s 400x400 -q:v 3 -f mp4 pipe:1
```

and I'm getting

> [mp4 @ 0x55a646cca340] muxer does not support non seekable output
> Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters
> ?): Invalid argument Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
> Conversion failed!

When I convert to mpeg it works fine.

```
ffmpeg -f mp4 -i pipe:0 -an -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -s 400x400 -q:v 3 -f mpeg pipe:1
```

Is this mean that I cannot output to mp4?
if so what is the best practice to convert video to be accepted from most browsers today?

Comment: Have you considered of letting FFmpeg to stream on its own? See [Streaming Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide), [RTSP streaming how-to](https://dev.to/tejasvi2/rtsp-stream-to-web-browser-using-ffmpeg-1cb), & [from video production stack exchange](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/25390)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. I'm trying to convert input stream to output stream in memory

Comment: Have you tried webm? (not telling you it'll work, just an idea) You can also look into whether your dev environment (os/lang/libraries) allows an easy access to a memory-mapped file. If so, use it instead of pipe

Comment: I did not, is webm part of the command?

Comment: webm is an alternative format to mp4, both of which are supported by web browsers. Check out this [FFmpeg Wiki entry](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9)

Comment: I'm not looking for that, thank you though. I need mp4 as a result

Comment: well then look into memory-mapped files, that would be your only hope AFAIK (or just use a temp file)

Comment: std in/out/err stream can't seek, and `mp4` mux format need seek. If you need mux as `mp4`, just don't use pipe. And if you need pipe, try another mux format such as `flv`.

Comment: With `memory-mapped files` or something else, just don't. Maybe ffmpeg seek and edit at some position, how you can handle it? Tell to target you need seek and edit too?